# Removing footer in SAP Crystal Reports 2011

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to set up a report to print an invoice with the company details as part of the PAGE footer.

I have also set up a terms and conditions section which I want printed after everything else and so have set it up as a REPORT footer.

This T & C page should NOT include the company information footer and should print on a SINGLE page.

I have set up a formula to suppress the page footer if the T&C's have been printed. This works and on other reports I have set up similarly, it does not push part of the T&C's on to a second page.

The problem I am having is that for this particular report the company information footer is several lines as opposed to a single line (as with the others) and so even though I suppress the footer on the T&C's Page, it still reserves that extra space where the footer would have gone and so pushes the end few lines of the T&C's to an additional page.

This probably happened before as well, but as the footers before had been a single line instead, there was still enough space to print the full T&C's on the page even after reserving the space for the footer.

Is there any way for me to suppress the footer without the space being reserved, or is even putting the suppressed footer in the 'background' so the rest of the T&C's can just print in front?

The client have specified a required font size and styling for the report so I cannot just reduce the size of the footer and/or the T&C's to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the section >> Section Expert >> check Suppress Blank Section, so if the section blank it will be suppressed and removing the footer extra empty space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I have already tried this solution. The footer is suppressed but there is still a blank space that appears at the bottom of the page.